# JSON.Stringify array with nested object arrays TypeScript/JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, typescript

I'm generating a object array with a series of nested objects (under the elements 'failReasons' and 'photos') - I then want to post the resultant array as JSON to a web API where it will expect a list of objects, with nested lists of objects. The first part works - the array receives a list of objects and can parse them, however, when converting my array to JSON the nested arrays are left empty.

This is the array I generate:
[image: Array]
And here is what it looks like when I stringify it:

```
{"capeNo":"ABCD1234","insDate":"2016-11-10 15:03:18","inspector":"User.Name","inspectionResult":"Pass","comments":"","site":"Site Name","dismCompleteDate":"","failReasons":[],"photos":[]}
```

As you can see, failReasons, which had 6 objects in its array before being stringified, is now just an empty array.

I'm using the following code to generate the array:

Interfaces:

```
export interface inspectionUpload {
        capeNo: string;
        insDate: string;
        inspector: string;
        inspectionResult: string;
        comments: string;
        site: string;
        dismCompleteDate;
        failReasons: Array<Object>;
        photos: Array<Object>;
}

export interface inspectionFailures {
        failCategory: string;
        failReason: string;
        resolution: string;
        inspectionId: string;
}

export interface inspectionPhotos {
        base64: string;
}
```

And this populates the array:

```
this.sql.query('SELECT rowid,* FROM InspectionResults_tbl').then((res) => {
    var arr = []

    for (var i = 0; i < res.res.rows.length; i++) {
        var item = res.res.rows.item(i);
        var header: inspectionUpload = {
            capeNo: item.capeNo,
            insDate: item.inspectionDT,
            inspector: item.inspectedBy,
            inspectionResult: item.result,
            comments: item.comment,
            site: this.SharedService.site,
            dismCompleteDate: item.dismantleDate,
            failReasons: < inspectionFailures[] > [],
            photos: < inspectionPhotos[] > []
        }

        if (item.result == 'Fail') {
            console.log(item);
            this.sql.query('SELECT * FROM InspectionFailures_tbl WHERE inspectionId = ?', [item.rowid]).then((res) => {
                for (var i = 0; i < res.res.rows.length; i++) {
                    var item = res.res.rows.item(i);
                    header.failReasons.push({
                        failCategory: item.failCategory,
                        failReason: item.failreason,
                        resolution: item.resolution,
                        FRId: item.FRId
                    })
                }
            })
        }

        this.sql.query('SELECT * FROM InspectionPhotos_tbl WHERE inspectionId = ?', [item.rowid]).then((res) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.res.rows.length; i++) {
                var item = res.res.rows.item(i);
                header.photos.push({
                    base64: item.base64
                })
            }
        })



        arr.push(header);
        if ((i + 1) == res.res.rows.length) upload(arr)
    }
})
```

And finally, to stringify it:

```
function upload(a) {
          console.log(a);
          console.log(JSON.stringify(a));
        }
```

Help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Those queries you do inside the callback for the outer query are just as asynchronous as that one. The arrays will be populated when those queries complete, but that will happen *after* the outer callback finishes.

Comment: @Pointy, if I follow, you're saying that the json.stringify is called before my failreasons and photos arrays have been populated? I had considered that, but I call the console.log of the array at the same time as I stringify it, and the data is visible at that time (as per the screenshot? - Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: The top level object you've logged, out of the top frame of your image, does it have a small blue `i` next to it?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean. Put some `console.log()` calls inside those inner callbacks, and one right before the `arr.push()` call to see.

Comment: @JamesThorpe, no, but it does have the array length, 24.

Comment: @Pointy Okay, I put the console.logs in the sub loops and as you suggested, the data does then appear in the JSON string   - in which case I have two questions: how can the data appear in my array  in the callback function (as per the screenshot above) if it isn't populated until after said function is called? Secondly, and more importantly, can you suggest how I could correct my code so that the callback isn't fired until all data is retrieved?

Comment: @Pointy, at a guess, a recursive function for the outer loop?

Comment: All of your SQL calls are **asynchronous**. The callback function will be invoked when the DBMS responds to the request, but the call to `this.sql.query()` returns **immediately**. Thus the statements after `this.sql.query()` will run before the code in the callback function runs.

Comment: @Pointy, so my callback should be nested in my SQL queries? Given that two of them both run in parallel and have no link other than the parent loop, how should you suggest I do that? My best guess is a series of three function's, one for the header row which calls the failure and photos functions - passing the data between them - and calls itself recursively, only proceeding when the other two functions have resolved ( one would have to be called when the other resolved) - sound about right?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because you print the stringified array before the promise is resolved.

```
        this.sql.query('SELECT * FROM InspectionFailures_tbl WHERE inspectionId = ?', [item.rowid]).then((res) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.res.rows.length; i++) {
                var item = res.res.rows.item(i);
                header.failReasons.push({
                    failCategory: item.failCategory,
                    failReason: item.failreason,
                    resolution: item.resolution,
                    FRId: item.FRId
                })
            }
        })
    ...

    arr.push(header);
    if ((i + 1) == res.res.rows.length) upload(arr)
```

it would stringify correctly if you did the below code (this isn't the proper way to do it, I'm just demonstrating that you can't stringify until the push in the then has completed populating the array...):

```
        var queryComplete = false;

        this.sql.query('SELECT * FROM InspectionFailures_tbl WHERE inspectionId = ?', [item.rowid]).then((res) => {
            for (var i = 0; i < res.res.rows.length; i++) {
                var item = res.res.rows.item(i);
                header.failReasons.push({
                    failCategory: item.failCategory,
                    failReason: item.failreason,
                    resolution: item.resolution,
                    FRId: item.FRId
                })
            }
            queryComplete = true;
        })
    ...

    while ( !queryComplete ){
        //noop
    }

    arr.push(header);
    if ((i + 1) == res.res.rows.length) upload(arr)
```